What is the relationship between Stream (java.util.stream) and LinkedList data structure in Java?
I'm learning about Stream in Java and want to figure out how it actually works.
And I saw an article by Brian Goetz. He wrote about the stream pipeline:

A stream pipeline is built by constructing a linked-list representation of the stream source and its intermediate operations

But, I don't understand this. What is the role of LinkedList in here? Why do they use LinkedList instead of other implementations of List like ArrayList?
I have checked the source code of Stream but didn't see any reference to LinkedList.

There is no relationship between those two classes.

Why exactly do you care? If they had used ArrayList wouldn't you be askig why they didn't use LinkedList?

I have no idea why this question merits closure. It's on-topic, of interest, clear, and to the point.

a "linked list" is a generic data structure and is independent of the actual Java implementation LinkedList

@user207421 yes, this is what I'm caring about. And of course If they had used ArrayList , I will be asking why they didn't use LinkedList.  I just want to clear and understand technology/library that I'm using. What's wrong with it ? :)

"I have checked the source code of Stream but didn't see any reference to LinkedList." - This should be your first signal that it doesn't actually use LinkedList - therefore, asking why it does, does not make sense. The second signal is the fact that the author wrote "linked-list" as a generic term, in lowercase with a hyphen, and not LinkedList formatted like a class name.

@KarlKnechtel Yes. you're right. My mistake was not paying attention to the proper spelling of "linked-list" and "LinkedList" in the post. However, with that oversight, I posed this question—does it now make sense ?

@KarlKnechtel And "I have checked the source code of Stream but didn't see any reference to LinkedList." is just my subjective observation upon inspecting the source code, and I could be entirely mistaken in my interpretation of it. I hope to engage in a discussion to collectively discern the issue. What's wrong with it ? :( As Robby Cornelissen commented above: It's on-topic, of interest, clear, and to the point.

Well as it turns out they didn’t use either of them, and your citation doesn’t say different. There are well-known reasons for preferring linked lists over arrays, and vice versa,, and they certainly apply in this case.

Concept, not class
The author refers to linked-list as a concept, not to the LinkedList class. The actual linked list implementation can be found in the java.util.stream package's AbstractPipeline class.
It's a doubly linked list where each stage contains a reference to the previousStage (if present) and nextStage (if present):
abstract class AbstractPipeline<E_IN, E_OUT, S extends BaseStream<E_OUT, S>>
        extends PipelineHelper<E_OUT> implements BaseStream<E_OUT, S> {
    /* ... */
    
    /**
     * The "upstream" pipeline, or null if this is the source stage.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected final AbstractPipeline previousStage;

    /* ... */
    
    /**
    * The next stage in the pipeline, or null if this is the last stage.
    * Effectively final at the point of linking to the next pipeline.
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private AbstractPipeline nextStage;
    
    /* ...*/
}

Nothing here warrants the additional overhead of an ArrayList or array-like implementation as no index-based access is required.

Correct, the concept of "linked list" predates Java by many decades.

This is basically saying that a stream pipeline such as:
someCollection.stream()
    .map(...)
    .filter(...)
    .limit(...);

Can be thought of as a linked list, where the first node is the source of the stream, and the rest of the node are the intermediate and terminal operations you do, such as
source <---> map <---> filter <---> limit

If you dig into the implementation, you will find something that looks very similar to a typical linked list implementation in AbstractPipeline.java.
abstract class AbstractPipeline<E_IN, E_OUT, S extends BaseStream<E_OUT, S>>
        extends ... {

    // ...

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private final AbstractPipeline previousStage;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private AbstractPipeline nextStage;

    // ...
}

Compare this with a typical implementation of a linked list:
class Node<T> {
    T element;
    Node<T> next;
    Node<T> previous;
}

Note that this is unrelated to java.util.LinkedList.

I don’t think he means an actual LinkedList object, but that each stage of the stream pipeline “knows” only its upstream neighbour, thus making the pipeline a linked list in the abstract sense.

He was using the term linked-list as a type of data structure, not a specific implementation of said structure.  The LinkedList in the API is a particular implementation of a linked list.  There is no explicit relationship between the API implementation of LinkedList and the use of a linked list in the implementation of the Stream interface.
